# SQL 'COUNT' Multiple Possible Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a T-SQL query that uses multiple joins to produce the results that I need. In the results output there are multiple records with the same 'Name' value, and a column titled "Event" which can have one of five events. So each 'Name' can have multiple 'Events' associated with them.

What I'm trying to do is count the occurrence of 'Event' for each 'Name'. Here's an example of the output produced currently, without the count:

```
Name         | Event
-------------+--------------
John Smith   | Decline
John Smith   | Decline
April Baker  | Accept
John Smith   | No Response
April Baker  | Decline
John Smith   | Accept
```

The outcome I am trying to produce is to show a single record/row for each unique 'Name' with the counts of each 'Event'. Using the example above that would be:

```
Name        | Accept | Decline | No Response
------------+--------+---------+--------------
John Smith  |    1   |    2    |      1
April Baker |    1   |    1    |      0
```

Or, if that isn't possible, then maybe something like this:

```
Name       | Event       | Count
-----------+-------------+--------
John Smith | Accept      |   1
John Smith | Decline     |   2
John Smith | No Response |   1
etc etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation with `subquery` or `cte` :

```
select name, 
       sum(case when event = 'Accept' then 1 else 0 end) as Accept,
       sum(case when event = 'Decline ' then 1 else 0 end) as Decline ,
       sum(case when event = 'No Response' then 1 else 0 end) as [No Response]
from ( <query> ) t
group by name;
```

If you want second outcome then `group by`  is enough with `count()` :

```
select name, Event, count(*)     
from ( <query> ) t
group by name, Event;
```

Comment: Spectacular! I was trying so hard to figure that one out but was getting nowhere. Thank you!